# UIPopoverController and UINavigationController cuts corners

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a problem with the display of my popover. After `initWithContentViewController:` and `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` it cuts corners of the navigation bar. How should I fix it?? Thanks.

[image: Clipping corners of navigation bar]

This is the code I'm using

```
    NavContr *nav = [NavContr new];
    nav.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIPopoverController *tempPop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
    [tempPop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:mainButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
```

**EDIT:** I have resolved this problem:

```
+ (void)configure:(UINavigationController *)navController {
    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = navController.navigationBar;       
    UIView *contentView = nil;

    for (UIView *view in navController.view.subviews) {
        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [view class]] isEqualToString:@"UILayoutContainerView"])
            contentView = view;
    }

    // setting frame to navigation bar and content view
    [navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(navigationBar.frame.origin.x, 0, navigationBar.frame.size.width, navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
    [contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(contentView.frame.origin.x, 0, contentView.frame.size.width, contentView.frame.size.height + navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

    [navController.view bringSubviewToFront:contentView];

    for (UIView *customView in contentView.subviews)
        customView.frame = CGRectMake(customView.frame.origin.x, customView.frame.origin.y + navigationBar.frame.size.height, customView.frame.size.width, customView.frame.size.height);

    [contentView addSubview:navigationBar];
    [contentView bringSubviewToFront:navigationBar];
}
```

Comment: Give please full code generating UIPopoverController

Comment: Try to add some viewController to your nav controller

Comment: You cannot change this functionality.  There may be some undocumented means to do it, but there is a fair chance that implementing it may get your app rejected by Apple.

Comment: @LastNight Your issue would be resolved check out my answer in this page. I replicated your scenario at my end and came to the conclusion. Check it out @ my answer.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440250/uipopovercontroller-nav-bar-appearance it works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably because you have no root view controller, or are otherwise fiddling with the navigation controller in ways it was not meant to be played with. This is how you ought to be setting up the popover:

```
MyCustomViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCustomViewController" bundle:nil]; //or storyboard or whatever
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController]; //you should have a root view controller before displaying the popover
tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIPopoverController *tempPop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
[tempPop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:mainButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
```

There are a few very important things going on here:

- Your navigation controller should have a root view controller before you display it.
- This code is using a standard `UINavigationController` instance. According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you should not subclass `UINavigationController`, nor should you try and reinvent the wheel. Apple has created a complex and comprehensive framework, UIKit, that you can use to build amazing apps. If you try and step outside the box, you'll be creating an awful lot of work for yourself without any appreciable benefit.
- This is using the `tintColor` property of the `UINavigationBar` class. If the tint is insufficient for your UI, you can also set the background image manually (refer to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)).

If you want to make a popover with a navigation controller, use the built-in `UINavigationController` class. Don't subclass it and don't reinvent it. To customize the appearance of the `navigationBar`, use the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` methods in the `UINavigationBar` class.

Answer (score 3):

I get the solution before add **CALayer** the UIPopOverController shows like [image: rounded]
after adding below lines in table view class i get the following UIPopOverController

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CALayer *imageLayer2 = self.tableView.layer;
[imageLayer2 setCornerRadius:-20];
[imageLayer2 setBorderWidth:1];
```

[image: non rounded]

Try it in your project may be it works!!
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have tried & replicate the issue you are facing, made some R&D. It's due to the line of code below :

```
nav.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

While you set the background color of the navigation bar it will behave weird due the native shape of the pop up. Try and remove the below line, you will definitely have issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying the Rect where the popover appears, we've found that using decimals can result in weird distortions like that.  Be sure you're using whole number for origin and size.